# New to Android, add Javascript to Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I know I need to use `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`,  but I'm unsure where to put it after following a tutorial.  This is literally my first app.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webhelper_detail, container, false);

    // Show the dummy content as text in a TextView.
    if (mItem != null) {
        ((WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webhelper_detail)).loadUrl(mItem.webHelper_url);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

That's the only block that uses WebView.  My issue is that the pages load without any javascript available.  I am following the tutorial at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you want to keep a reference to your web view. So before your onCreateView define a variable for it like so:

```
WebView mWebView;
```

Then inside your onCreateView after you assign your web view you can add settings to it:

```
mWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webhelper_detail)
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(mItem.webHelper_url);
```

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!  I'm going to read up on it and make sure I understand what's happening before I try my next rev.  Thanks again!